# Placing a login feature inside a menu (C++)

Tags: c++, authentication, menu

I'm working on a C++ project with a login system.

It seems that I have placed the login feature on the wrong side. Since the login system is working, but whenever I want to go back to the menu, it asks me to login again? Also after each step it asks me to log in again.

How can I fix this? AKA: getting access to the full menu after a succesfull login?

This is the code I have:

```
char menuVesStock::menuVesStockOptions()
{

    VestigingDAO manager;
    string Mgr_name, Mgr_pass;

    cout << "\n\n * * * * - B R I C O    S T O C K  M E N U  - * * * *" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter manager login" << endl;
    cout << "Name: ";
    cin >> Mgr_name;
    if (Mgr_name.empty())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        Mgr_pass = hiddenline("Password: ");
        Vestiging* managermemb = manager.getManagerByName(Mgr_name);

        if (managermemb == 0)
        {
            return -2;
        }
        else {
            if (managermemb->getMgr_pass() == Mgr_pass)
            {
                cout << "Welcome to the menu!" What would you like to do?\n";
                cout << endl;
                cout << "1 - Add products" << endl;
                cout << "2 - Delete products" << endl;
                cout << "3 - Show products" << endl;
                cout << "0 - Go back" << endl;

        }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return _getch();


}

void menuVesStock::menu(int storeID)
{
    bool goOn = true;
    while (goOn)
    {
        switch (menuVesStockOptions())
        {
        case '0':
            goOn = false;
            break;
        case '1':
            //saveProduct();
            break;
        case '2':
            //delHoofd_Stock();
            break;
        case '3':
            vesStockList(storeID);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong choice!" << endl << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are being asked to login constantly is because the login is in `menuVesStockOptions()` (where you also process what the user wishes to do). You should be able to fix this by having the user login first, then asking for their option in a `while` loop:

```
menu(int storeID)
{
    // Ask for user to login. If it's successful, let them manage inventory etc
    if (UserLogin())
    {
        bool goOn = true;
        while (goOn)
        {
            // no longer handles user login. Optionally you could pass the user to the function
            switch(menuVesStockOptions())
            {
                // as before
            };
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // User login failed. Handle it:
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, would this also mean to put my login function in a new function? (UserLogin() ) called in your code